# Regex Excel Remove Middle Part of String

Tags: regex, excel, string, geocoding

I have some address data that needs to be corrected. It is intending to show a range of addresses, but this will not work for geocoding. What is an effective way to to remove everything between the hyphen and the first space using regex in excel? Example:

```
    29-45  SICKLES ST
    31-39  SHERMAN AV
    36-44  ARDEN ST
   118-22  NAGLE AV
```

Becomes

```
    29 SICKLES ST
    31 SHERMAN AV
    36 ARDEN ST
   118 NAGLE AV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged `RegEx` you could use it like so within Excel's VBA:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("29-45  SICKLES ST", "31-39  SHERMAN AV", "36-44  ARDEN ST", "118-22  NAGLE AV")

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "-\d*\s*"
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(x) = .Replace(arr(x), " ")
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The 'pattern' part of the above answer worked in a find and replace query. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Gra, your question was "How to do this in Excel", are you using other software doing this query?

Comment: I am using OpenOffice. I cannot accept the answer until 5 minutes after it is posted...accepting soon.

Answer (score 0):

You will create a new column by `= REGEXREPLACE(current_column,"-\d+ ","")`